Serve apple-app-site-association file using vercel results in 404
I'm having a lot of trouble getting the hand off to occur for app site association and I've checked multiple discussions on github, stackoverflow, and tried AI and no luck.
I'm working on setting app-site-association for my site. I've added the app-site-association file to public/.well-known/app-site-association and confirmed that my file made it to apple CDN. I've also checked it on branch.io and confirmed the configuration is correct.
The problem is, when I head to my site with the app association link, for example mysite.com/order/32312 I get a 404. I checked sysdiagnose logs and can see the same
Error Domain=SWCErrorDomain Code=7 "SWCERR00101 Bad HTTP Response: 404 Not Found -- 
{"status":"404 Not Found"}" UserInfo={Line=275, Function=-[SWCDownloader. 
URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveResponse:completionHandler:], NSDebugDescription=SWCERR00101 
Bad HTTP Response: 404 Not Found -- {"status":"404 Not Found"}, UnderlyingError=Error 
Domain=HTTP Code=404 "(null)" UserInfo={Line=275, Function=-[SWCDownloader 
URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveResponse:completionHandler:]}}


In my vercel json I've added the following
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Content-Type",
          "value": "application/json"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/.well-known/:path*",
      "destination": "/.well-known/:path*"
    }
  ]
}

I'm not really sure where to go from here.
